# Ruby empty parameter in function

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to enqueue various functions in a generic way with this code :

```
{ Object.const_get(object_name).new(job[:params]||={}).delay(:queue => queue).send(method_name)}
```

`job` is a Hash where I get the name, objects parameters etc...

My problem is in this case :

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

`Foo` doesn't take parameters for its instanciation.

So if I use the previous line with `Foo` as `object_name` I'll get this error :

```
ArgumentError: wrong number pf arguments (1 for 0)
```

And I absolutly don't want to write something like that :

```
if job.has_key?[:param] then
  Object.const_get(object_name).new(job[:params]||={}).delay(:queue => queue).send(method_name)
else
  Object.const_get(object_name).new().delay(:queue => queue).send(method_name)
end
```

What could I write instead of `job[:params]||={}` so it works for every case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can achieve this with using `Foo.send` and using an array. but is it worth it?

Comment: @akonsu I don't get it. Can you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: like `myparams = ['new', 1, 2, 3]; Foo.send *myparams`.

Comment: Yep, I get it now, but it won't fit into the code logic unfortunatly

Comment: why not? `Object.const_get(object_name).send(*(job.has_key(:param) ? ['new', job[:param]] : ['new']))` But this is ugly.

Comment: Ah yep, well I think I'll do it this way. you should write it as an anwser so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with using Foo.send and using an array.

For instance

```
Object.
  const_get(object_name).
  send(*(job.has_key?(:param) ? ['new', job[:param]] : ['new']))...
```

I personally think it is not worth it and an `if` statement is easier on the eyes.

Comment: The method is spelled `has_key?`.

Answer (score 1):

The `initialize` method of your `Foo` class should receive a parameter with a default value. Like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(params={})
    # Here you do stuff like checking if params is empty or whatever.
  end
end
```

This way you will achieve the two behaviors.

Comment: But I would have to change the initialize method of *all* the classes... I don't want to do that

Comment: Well, i think so. Couldn't think of something else.

Comment: if `Foo` does not need a parameter, what is the point of introducing one? Just to fix the code that misuses `Foo`? :)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser anyway ;)

Comment: I think this is better than messing with the code on the other part. Constructors have the default idea that they always require something to work. So i believe it is a valid thought.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I think the test you accepted might be wrong.  Your code suggests that you shouldn't be testing whether the :params key exists in the hash, you should be testing whether initialize takes an argument.  If initialize does take an argument, then you send it an argument regardless of whether the :params key exists in the hash. The accepted answer will fail when the :params key doesn't exist in the hash, and yet the initialize method takes an argument--you'll get a 0 for 1 error.  Is that a possibility?

```
class Dog
  def initialize(params)
    p params
    puts "dog"
  end
end

class Cat
  def initialize
    puts "cat"
  end
end

class_names = ["Dog", "Cat"]

job = {
  params: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
}

class_names.each do |class_name|
  class_obj = Object.const_get(class_name)

  if class_obj.instance_method(:initialize).arity == 0
    send_args = 'new'
  else
    send_args = 'new', job[:params] ||= {}
  end

  class_obj.send(*send_args)
end

--output:--
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
dog
cat
```